# Get textboxes in to a list! c#

Tags: c#

```
 public class Account
        {
            public string Username
            {
                get { return Username; }
                set { Username = value; }
            }
        }


public class ListAcc
        {
            static void Data()
            {
                List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>();
                //example of adding user account
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Username = textBox1.Text; //error
                UserList.Add(acc);
            }
        }
```

there are a error from access to textBox1.Text? ( An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property)... Someone can help?

but if the code is:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>();
            //example of adding user account
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Username = textBox1.Text;
            UserList.Add(acc);
    }
```

it's work! someone can help me fix my error? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextBox1 is a member variable which cannot be accessed in a static method.
You can have your code as below.

```
public class ListAcc 
{
            private static List<Account> UserList;
            public static List<Account> Data() 
            { 
                 return UserList;
            } 
        }
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
            UserList = new List<Account>(); 
            //example of adding user account 
            Account acc = new Account(); 
            acc.Username = textBox1.Text; 
            UserList.Add(acc); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the `Data` method is static and `textBox1_TextChanged` is not. `textBox1` is an instance variable, it belongs to a specific instance of your class. `static` methods belong to the class itself and cannot see instance variables. `static` methods would not know which instance to talk to.

Why do you want the `Data` method to be `static`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a field/property/method of an object (in this case textBox1 from the container object e.g a WinForm object) from a static method without using a reference to the object e.g **form1.TextBox1**. TextBox1 is also probably private inside your container object e.g form1 so you won't be able to access it outside the form1 object in your ListAcc object either.

Below is some sample code that should work.

```
public class ListAcc
{
    // Don't put this in Data or you'll recreate it again and 
    // again when you call Data
    private static List<Account> UserList = new List<Account>();

    // We'll pass in textBox1.Text via name parameter instead of 
    // referencing it directly which we can't
        public static void Data(string name)
        {
            //example of adding user account
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Username = name;
            UserList.Add(acc);
        }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // We'll call Data and pass in textBox1.Text as our UserName
    ListAcc.Data(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Note that TextChanged event is not exactly the best place to put your Data method because it is raised everytime you enter a new character/press backspace/etc.

Comment: yeah, i think so! so, what is the best way to get the complete string in all textboxes?

Comment: Use a Button and handle the click event of that button to get the text in each TextBox and call the Data method. A For loop will work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

textBox1 is object variable which belong to **object**, so you need to create object (instance of) of ListAcc class before you use it.

void Data() is static method which belong to **class** *not object*, this mean you can use them without create instance of it.

From your source code you try to use textBox1 (which must belong to object) inside static method and this is unreasonable to do. You can solve this problem by remove static keyword or remove textBox1 from this method.